# Reaching DC/OS services via DNS

Tags: dcos

In other PAAS (e.g. cloud foundry) the setup for reaching hosted services is this:

1. PAAS is configured to accept mycloud.example.com subdomain.
2. External DNS servers return all *.mycloud.example.com queries to point to IP of PAAS.
3. PASS's built in proxy takes all such traffic and sends it to the correct service.

How is this done in DC/OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the service discovery docs of DC/OS:

- https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/

and specifically

- https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/
- https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/marathon-lb-basic-tutorial/

You should run Marathon-LB on you public agents an point your loadbalancer to the respective IPs. Also create the appropriate A or CNAME records for your (sub-)domains pointing to your loadbalancer.